# ListBoxDragDropTarget prevents ListBox from filling its parent control

Tags: silverlight, listbox

Its extremely easy with the Silverlight Toolkit to enable basic drag and drop.

http://silverlightfeeds.com/post/1325/Silverlight_Toolkit_adds_DragDrop_targets.aspx

Unfortunately it seems that the wrapper `ListBoxDragDropTarget` screws up the normal default behavior of a ListBox which is to stretch itself to the parent control - such as a grid cell in this example.

```
<Grid Background="Yellow">

 <toolKit:ListBoxDragDropTarget AllowDrop="True">
      <ListBox x:Name="customerListBoxMain" 
               DisplayMemberPath="Name">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      </ListBox>
    </toolKit:ListBoxDragDropTarget>

</Grid>
```

I end up here (after binding data to the `ListBox`) with a small listbox  resized to fit its contents sitting in the middle of a yellow box.

No amount of `HorizontalAlignment=Stretch` etc. seems to be able to get it to fill the parent box.

How can I get the `ListBox` to fill the `Grid`?

Answer (score 6):

ListBoxDragDropTarget is derived from content control. Just set HorizontalContentAlignment and 
VerticalContentAlignment.

.....

Comment: Actually, this did work for me! Make sure you don't set Width/Height on the ListBox and set Vertical/HorizontalContentAlignment to Stretch.

Comment: Just stumbled across this post, and this solution worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best I have so far is listening for the size of the wrapper grid to change, and manually updating the size. (I couldn't get this working in XAML so had to use the event).

```
<Grid Name="myListBoxWrapper" SizeChanged="myListBoxWrapper_SizeChanged">               
  <controlsToolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget AllowDrop="True">                  
    <ListBox x:Name="myListBox" >
```

and in code-behind:

```
private void myListBoxWrapper_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        myListBox.Width = myListBoxWrapper.ActualWidth;
        myListBox.Height = myListBoxWrapper.ActualHeight;
    }
```

Comment: it turns out that currently the dragging functionality isn't stable enough for me and i ended up with all kinds of wierdness anyway..

Answer (score 0):

As Archil said, setting `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` is the way to go, but another way probably would be to bind `Width` and `Height` of `ListBox` to `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of `ListBoxDragDropTarget`:

```
<toolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget x:Name="dragdroptarget" AllowDrop="True">
    <ListBox x:Name="customerListBoxMain" 
        DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
            Width="{Binding ElementName=dragdroptarget, Path=ActualWidth}" 
            Height="{Binding ElementName=dragdroptarget, Path=ActualHeight}" >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</toolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget>
```